# Add migration and then delete migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rather than having 20,000 migration files over the next 5 years, is there a better way to scale a Rails app? For example, I want to add a column to a Model without creating *another* migration file.

Can I, for example, create a new migration to add a column, migrate the changes, and then remove the migration file? Is there a better way to handle this as the application scales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you keep the `schema.rb` file, you are free to delete the old migration files. (But first make sure you have run the migrations before deleting them!)

You can use `rake db:schema:dump` to create an up to date schema file.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for this suggestion. Never knew this!

Comment: So technically, I could create a migration file, migrate the changes, use `rake db:schema:dump`, and then delete the migration file?

Comment: when you run the migration you rails would automatically generate the new schema file. As long you keep that it ought to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can add the column manually in the mysql/pqsql/oracle client, and then edit the original migration file to add the column. Something like:

```
t.integer :new_column_level, null: false, default: 1
```

but then all the servers where the app is installed must be updated manually. One advantage of migration files is that capistrano will run the changes in the next deployment.

I also try to avoid new migration files and I do so, but that's because I know and handle all my servers.

Comment: Gotcha. That sounds like a pretty good idea. I'm only going to have this application on two servers, so that might actually work out for me.